# Selenium with Python - how to find element on dynamic Javascript form?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate searches on http://matrix.itasoftware.com/, and I'm having trouble locating the element on the fields I'm planning to use - the form the website uses is generated via Javascript AFAIK. I'm stumped on the first field: under the Multi-city tab, under Flight 1, on the "Departing from" field.

Using Selenium IDE, I managed to locate the ID for this particular field: `ita_form_multislice_MultiSliceRow_0_origin`, but testing this out returns an error "NoSuchElementException".

My code:

```
flight1_origin = driver.find_element_by_id("ita_form_multislice_MultiSliceRow_0_origin")
```

The website generates the form via Javascript, so it's difficult to locate the actual IDs and everything via normal means. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not on the tab.  That element does not actually get appended to the DOM until the tab gets clicked.

Add this to your script before trying to find the departing from field.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ita_layout_TabContainer_0_tablist_ita_form_multislice_MultiSliceForm_0").click()
```